# How to publish to AWS Shadow from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

This is the code Iam using,

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: '###########.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  var params = {
  payload: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE'  
  encoded on your behalf */, /* required */
  thingName: 'ESP32', /* required */
  //shadowName: 'STRING_VALUE'
 };
 iotdata.updateThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
  
};
```

I referred to this from the given link,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IotData.html#updateThingShadow-property

But I cant update my shadow.
I also dont understand in which format I should include the payload.

I am running this on AWS Lambda function in Nodejs 12.x environment. I also dont receive any errors in cloudwatch . Cloudwatch tells me execution result has succeeded? Can you help me?

I have already given permission for Lambda to updateShadow.

Comment: What research have you done before asking the question and from that what have you already tried?

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry about that. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This the final correct code .....

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: '#######.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

var POST_DATA = JSON.stringify({"state":{"desired":{"state":10}}});
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var params = {
  payload:POST_DATA , 
  
  thingName: 'ESP32', /* required */
  //shadowName: 'STRING_VALUE'
 };
  iotdata.updateThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) { 
         console.log(err, err.stack); 
         console.log("error................")// an error occurred
         reject(err);
      } else {
         console.log(data);           // successful response
         resolve(data)
      }
 });
})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using the async Lambda handler. So while your updateThingShadow() call is in progress, the Lambda function completes and exits. You need to wait for that call to complete. There are two ways to do that -

**Approach 1**: (A simpler async-await syntax)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: '###########.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  var params = {
  // Define params
  };
  try {
        const data = await iotdata.updateThingShadow(params).promise();
        console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
  }
};
```

**Approach 2**: (If you prefer using the callback approach)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: '###########.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  var params = {
  // Define params
  };
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      iotdata.updateThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
         if (err) { 
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            reject(err); // End the promise with an error
         } else {
            console.log(data); // successful response
            resolve(data); // End the promise with success
         }
      });
   }) 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this. I have a small problem. where should this be placed in my code. For both the approaches where should I place them in my code?

Comment: Can I also konw in what format should the payload be given. I have a problem understanding that

Comment: I still have some problem. Is the following code correct ?

Comment: {
  "state": {
    "desired": {
      "color": {
        "r": 10
      },
      "engine": "ON"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I want to publish something like this. How can I do that?

Comment: Before I close the answer can you please explain me how the **approach 1**  works. It looks like  **approach 2**  cannot be implemented for my case. Now I am going for  **approach 1**  but I cant figure out where to place the **try**  and **catch**. Can you please provide me a full code. Highly appreciated

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. I've edited my answer to show the complete code for both approaches. I cannot comment on what goes inside the params as that depends on your use case, but the logic with async-await or Promise(resolve, reject) is common for any AWS SDK function that you are using. That should work for you.